# No ASP.NET 5 / Core Template in Visual Studio Community Update 3

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded Visual Studio Community yesterday and installed it to try out .NET Core.

[image]

The Web template section shows the templates for Version 4 but only has one option 'Get ASP.NET 5 RC'.

Here is what I have:

[image]

I have modified the installation and following what others have said online and updating the Web Tools with no success.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Visual Studio, You have to download and install **VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2**.

Steps are :

1. Install Visual Studio 2015 Community with Update 3
2. Download VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 from [Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935).

Now when you will go to install the Tooling Preview, you will get the message that you need to install the VS 2015 Update 3, **It's a known Bug**. You have to install Tooling Preview from command line with command

```
DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1
```

Just go in the folder and hit where Preview installer is.

Once done restart Visual Studio and now you will have the Scaffolding options like [image]