# how do I find out if I have asp.net CORE

Tags: asp.net

I have been asked to update my Visual Studio with asp.net core.  But the update told me I already have this component.  However when I look in the list for New Project I can find nothing which includes the word CORE. 
How do I work this out?

I'm not talking about a single Visual Studio Project or File.  I'm talking about the whole program. I have to update the program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Tooling Preview 2 to get the asp.net core templates. That is a bug in the visual studio 2015. Please follow the [following steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38867499/1367653) to resolve this issue

Comment: ok, so I have to install Tooling Preview 2 BEFORE I will be able to install the update 3 that I want.

Comment: Not sure how to install something from the command line.  Do I just open the windows command line and type in that line:
DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1
and then hit Enter??

Comment: @Monkey open the command line and move to the folder where DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe resides and then hit the command

Comment: First install  the update 3 or more and then install preview2.exe

Comment: I CAN'T install update 3.  That's part of the big problem.  When I try to I get a message saying I already have that component.  But I know I don't, because I looked.

Comment: i think you already have update 3..and you just need to install this preview 2. Same things happened with me 3 months back.

Comment: Thankyou Ashish. I installed the Tooling Preview which seems to have solved the problem.  I now have the CORE components.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your add new project dialog will look like once you have .net core installed correctly. Were you able to resolve this?[image: Dotnet core projects]

Comment: The tutor told us to go here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core and download VS update 3 which would then update my VS with asp.net core. But when I tried to install the update it said I already have that component. And I know from checking my VS that I DON'T have asp.net core.

Comment: Yes, thankyou, I downloaded and installed Tooling Preview, which was suggested by Ashish Rajput and my CORE components then appeared in the project dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Is it a console app or a web app? If you have a `.xproj` file in your Visual Studio project, then you have ASP.NET Core web application. Probably the same for an ASP.NET Core console application.